# UILabel Pixelated on Zoom in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uilabel, pinchzoom

I have a `UILabel` which added in `UIView` and this view add as subview of `UIScrollView`and zooming is enabled. Working every thing fine but when I zoom in then UILabel and other properties too and this look quite odd.I also added following code for flexible size.

```
    userResizableView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
userResizableView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

Above View is `UIView Type.
And below is code of Label

```
UILabel * lbl_FormFieldName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, rect.size.width, 15)];
lbl_FormFieldName.attributedText = attrText;

//    lbl_FormFieldName.text = text;
lbl_FormFieldName.autoresizingMask =  (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
lbl_FormFieldName.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lbl_FormFieldName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lbl_FormFieldName.font = customFont;
lbl_FormFieldName.numberOfLines = 0;
lbl_FormFieldName.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines; // or UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters, or UIBaselineAdjustmentNone

lbl_FormFieldName.clipsToBounds = YES;
lbl_FormFieldName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Kindly give me any suggestion how to make good. Looking for suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the frame label is using floating numbers. Try this to force integers value for your frame:

```
[label setFrame:CGRectIntegral(label.frame)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
As per my requirement I have added pinch gesture on uilabel like this :

1. Add this line before implementation. 
CG_INLINE CGRect CGRectScale(CGRect rect, CGFloat wScale, CGFloat hScale)
{
    return CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * wScale, rect.origin.y * hScale, rect.size.width * wScale, rect.size.height * hScale);
}

2. Add gesture on label

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewDidPinch:)];
pinch.delegate =self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:pinch];

3. Add method in your file. Add scrollview bounds instead of self.bounds as I have different scenario in my case.
- (void)viewDidPinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender
{

   CGFloat scale = sender.scale;

    CGRect scaleRect = CGRectScale(self.bounds, scale, scale);

       if (scaleRect.size.width >= 5 && scaleRect.size.height >= 5) {


           [self._label setAttributedText:[self getScaledStringFrom:self._label.attributedText withScale:scale]];

             [self._label setFrame:self.bounds];

    }
     sender.scale=1.0;

}

4. Rewrite text with new scale 
- (NSMutableAttributedString*) getScaledStringFrom:(NSMutableAttributedString*)string withScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    [string beginEditing];
    [string enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
        if (value) {
            UIFont *oldFont = (UIFont *)value;
            UIFont *newFont = [oldFont fontWithSize:oldFont.pointSize * scale];
            [string removeAttribute:NSFontAttributeName range:range];
            [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:newFont range:range];
        }
    }];
    [string endEditing];
    return string;
}
```